# Why is Force.com aimed at employees?

Tags: apex, licenses, business-logic, force

I am new to Salesforce and am reviewing it for an organisation who are planning to build a customer-facing application.

I notice in several places in the Salesforce marketing material that Force.com is geared towards internal applications - i.e. applications for employees, not customers.

Why is that?  Is Apex not as fully fledged as other OO development languages?  Is the Force licensing model not conducive to customer facing applications?  Some other reason perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The platform in and of itself is not customer-averse. However, you probably don't want to buy all your customers a license, nor do you want to give them too much data access. Take a look at [Community Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/communities/overview/), which is in fact designed to be customer facing.

Another option is to use `Site` pages, which can be easily integrated with a branded website.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's brandability driven.

Salesforce and Salesforce1 (mobile app) aren't super-brandable, so it's easier for a company to ask its employees to use Salesforce than to ask your customers to.  And if you're going to write massive amounts of code for brand reasons, you're giving up some of the plarform's advantages.

Another is user scale.  There are some limits on how many "internal" users can be in an org, and it's a much higher number for customer community.

That's two reasons communities are used more often for customer/partner scenarios, rather than standard force.com licenses.